# Perl: варианты перехвата создания файлов?

Tags: perl

Имеется проект из груды **[*]** чужого кода, в котором хорошо бы вычислить моменты создания определённых файлов. Разглядывание исходников, работа с отладчиком, логами etc осложняются тем, что часть проекта крутится под FGCI, часть - в виде демонов, и взаимодействие всех компонентов далеко не всегда прозрачное. К тому же файлы, которые надо отследить, не регулярные (с ними всё понятно), а временные/служебные, и создающиеся не так предсказуемо.

Первой мыслью было задействовать [File::Monitor](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Monitor), но она тут же самоликвидировалась по очевидным причинам (можно повесить `scan()` с вполне информативными коллбэками асинхронно, но нельзя проследить из какого именно места создан файл).

Второе решение, слепленное на скорую руку, не менее очевидно (там только `open` используется, так что этого хватит):

```
sub my_open( *;$@ )
{
    # сохраняем стек callers, аргументы
    # и вызываем CORE::open
}

BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::open = \&my_open;
}
```

На выходе получаются записи такого вида, по 1 на каждый вызов `open`:

```
TRACE_OPEN(">","/tmp/0.638145504593016.$$$"):
from W::abc()
 from X::bar()
  from Y::new()
   from Z::foo()
```

В принципе оно пока устраивает, но нельзя ли поизящней? На выходе нужно то же самое или аналогичное.

**[*]** На самом деле не так чтобы смертельно много, но...

```
$ cloc . --match-f='[.]p[ml]$'
     156 text files.
     156 unique files.                                          
      55 files ignored.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.60  T=7.96 s (19.6 files/s, 10802.5 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Perl                           192          18663           6092          64518
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: inotify? strace с правильными флагами

Comment: @strangeqargo,  inotify не подойдёт ровно по тем же причинам, что и File::Monitor (да и делает то же самое). А насчёт strace можно подробней? Что именно нужно получить сейчас допишу в вопрос.

Comment: вот тут  я бы посмотрел, https://linux-audit.com/the-ultimate-strace-cheat-sheet/

Comment: @strangeqargo, можно точней - где там трассировка перловых исходников? (подсказываю: нигде...)

Comment: он отловит все обращения к ФС, вот я о чем, хотя, конечно, прикрутить это к перлу... ну, как вариант, можно впилится прямо в код перла и пересобрать

Comment: @strangeqargo, а вы точно прочитали вопрос? И действительно поняли о чём там речь?

Comment: ты хочешь отловить трэйсбэк создания файлов?

Comment: @strangeqargo, именно. На  уровне перловых исходников, а не на уровне libc/ФС. Более того, я уже это делаю чисто перловым хаком, который пишется за 5 минут на коленке. Зачем мне "впиливаться в код перла", когда это уже сделано лёгким движением руки,  и тратить мегатрудодни на реализацию нереализуемого (ибо "only perl can parse perl") - непонятно.